# Excluding test folders from python install path

Tags: python, python-2.7, yocto, openembedded

When preparing an image for device I'd like to exclude test folders from
python install path, i.e. folders like:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/test
/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/test
...
```

Could you please advice is there a configure option for python recipe to exclude these folders?

Or maybe some other python recipe modification?

Thanks in advance